# Using a session variable in a SQL WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables, where-clause

I have a page with multiple forms using different .php pages to process and update my db. On the first page my session variable is stored on the second I'm trying to recall the session variable to use in my where statement.

```
$sql="UPDATE Persons
    SET newsletter='$_POST[newsletter]',howiPad='$_POST[howiPad]',invite='$_POST[invite]', messageforfriends='$_POST[messageforfriends]', possible_points='$_POST[possible_points]'
    WHERE `usremail` = '$_SESSION['usremail']'";
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: is it just not updating or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql="UPDATE Persons
    SET newsletter='$_POST[newsletter]',howiPad='$_POST[howiPad]',invite='$_POST[invite]', messageforfriends='$_POST[messageforfriends]', possible_points='$_POST[possible_points]'
    WHERE `usremail` = '$_SESSION[usremail]'";
```

Comment: it was hard for me to see the change but I agree that this is probably correct. Remove the single quotes inside the brackets around usremail otherwise you have single quotes inside of single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Just like any array inside a mysql statement, be sure to never in case it in quotes, single or double.

Basically just copy your post array to the where and change to session and usremail

Answer (score 0):

Ex.

```
$statement = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT id,
       usrname,
       color,
       chattext,
       chattime
FROM chat
WHERE id > ?
  AND usrname ='$_SESSION[usrname]'
  AND chattime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 HOUR)");
$statement->bind_param( 'i', $id);
```